# Jquery focus() selects whole textbox text

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm using focus() api of jquery to show focus on textbox.The focus is shown in all browsers perfectly except chrome.In chrome browser it shows whole text of textbox as selected and I just want to show the cursor for the textbox,can anyone tell how to avoid this behavior of chrome browser ?

`Please refer fiddle link(open in chrome) :` http://jsfiddle.net/XnJM7/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *workaround* (not the most elegant perhaps). Resetting the value to the same as before will cause the selection to be reset as well.

```
$("#test").focus().val(function() { return this.value; });
```